# Error when trying to create k8s Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

Created the yaml file below and launched the kubectl command, then got the error.

Could someone lent me a couple of fresh eyes and let me kow if are indentations or something else? I have tried with different clusters and same output error.

kubectl apply -f C:\Users\jmlp1\Documents\holy-api.yaml

Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "C:\Users\jmlp1\Documents\holy-api.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ObjectMeta.spec.template.metadata.labels of type map[string]string

```
 kind: Deployment
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 metadata:
   name: holy-api
   namespace: pluto
 spec:
   replicas: 3
   selector:
     matchLables:
       id:holy-api
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         id:holy-api
     spec:
       containers:
       - env:
       - name: CACHE_KEY_1
         value: "b&MTCi0=[T66RXm!jO@"
       - name: CACHE_KEY_2
         value: "PCAILGej5Ld@Q%{Q1=#"
       - name: CACHE_KEY_3
         value: "2qz-]2OJlWDSTn_;RFQ"
       image: nginx:1.17.3-alpine
       name: holy-api-container
       volumeMounts:
       - mountPath: /cache1
         name: cache-volume1
       - mountPath: /cache2
         name: cache-volume2
       - mountPath: /cache3
         name: cache-volume3
     volumes:
     - name: cache-volume1
       emptyDir: {}
     - name: cache-volume2
       emptyDir: {}
     - name: cache-volume3
       emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to edit your question and properly format the deployment manifest as a code sample. It is currently unreadable. There is help available on the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after the colon between the label name and the label value in `spec.template.metadata`:

```
 kind: Deployment
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 metadata:
   name: holy-api
   namespace: pluto
 spec:
   replicas: 3
   selector:
     matchLables:
       id: holy-api
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         id: holy-api
...
```